# Using initMap and initAutocomplete on same html page google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have a webpage where I would like to use both place autocomplete as well as google map with marker. User can search for an address in place autocomplete. Lat-long data for marker comes from DB and this doesn't change. The problem is either map works or place autocomplete, but not both, and the issue is related to callbacks.

From google docs, I've included both callbacks in separate API calls:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API KEY]&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API KEY]&callback=initMap"></script>
```

But this throws error on console, and nothing works.

> Error: You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

My question is: How multiple callbacks can be passed to Google API?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't add multiple callbacks (and you shouldn't include the API more than once).  Put all the code in a single callback.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API KEY]&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>

function initialize() {
   initMap();
   initAutoComplete();
}
```

or see [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

```js
function initialize() {
  initMap();
  initAutocomplete();
}
var map, marker;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
      },
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
  // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
  // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
  }
  if (!marker) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
  } else marker.setMap(null);
  marker.setOptions({
    position: place.geometry.location,
    map: map
  });

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#locationField,
#controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
}
#autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99%;
}
.label {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  color: #303030;
}
#address {
  border: 1px solid #000090;
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
  width: 480px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
#address td {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.field {
  width: 99%;
}
.slimField {
  width: 80px;
}
.wideField {
  width: 200px;
}
#locationField {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
      <input class="field" id="route" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField">
      <input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="country" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are a lifesaver @geocodezip. I don't have enough rep points to make this a comment however to continue on @goecodezip's answer, my map wouldn't work in association to the autocomplete and found the HTML temple I was using had an invalid `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` which caused the map to not appear.

To answer your question in the comment @Mamulasa regarding storing the lat and long into your DB, Setup two hidden input fields for lat and lon:

```
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="lat" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="lon" value="">
```

and in @geocodezip's example above add:

document.getElementById("latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById("longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

within the fillInAddress so this function will now look like this:

```
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
  }
  if (!marker) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });
  } else marker.setMap(null);
  marker.setOptions({
    position: place.geometry.location,
    map: map
  });

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  //-- ADD LAT AND LON HERE TO APEND TO HIDDEN HTML INPUT 
  document.getElementById("latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById("longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
```

Wrap the html in a `<form method="post">` and you will now be able to obtain all fields including a hidden lat and lon to store in your DB.

Hope this helps.