# We are using three different maps on different pages and it works in Chrome, but?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

On my website we are using three different maps in two different pages(first one is used in the header). 
And it seems to me that I can't get it to work. 
So currently two out of three maps are working. 
This is the code that I am using:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ICLEI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/selection.css') }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo:400,200,300,600,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{YOUR-API-KEY}}&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js') }}"><\/script>')</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.main.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-2790248-3"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-2790248-3');
    </script>
    <script>
    var locations = [{
        lat: 37.4,
        lng: 128.4,
        "government_local_name": "\ud3c9\ucc3d\uad70",
        "city": "Pyeongchang County",
        "country": "Republic of Korea",
        "website": "eng.pc.go.kr"
    },
        {
            lat: 10.5,
            lng: 122.43,
            "government_local_name": "Bayan ng Dumangas",
            "city": "Dumangas",
            "country": "Philippines",
            "website": null
        }];

        var image = '{{ asset('images/marker-office.png') }}';

        function initMap() {
            var options = { imagePath: '{{ asset('images/m') }}'};

            var map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('map1'), {
                    zoom: 2,
                    center: {lat: 50.7374, lng: 7.0982},
                }
            );

            var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
                return new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    icon: image
                });
            });

            var activeInfoWindow;

            markers.forEach(function(marker, i) {
                if(!locations[i].government_local_name){} else {
                    government = locations[i].government_local_name;
                }
                if(!locations[i].city){} else {
                    city = locations[i].city;
                }
                if(!locations[i].country) {} else {
                    country = locations[i].country;
                }
                if(!locations[i].website){} else {
                    website = locations[i].website;
                }
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<p>"+ government +"</p>" +
                    "<p>"+ city +"</p>" +
                    "<p>"+ country +"</p>" +
                    "<p>"+ website +"</p>"
                });

                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    if (activeInfoWindow === infowindow) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (activeInfoWindow) {
                        activeInfoWindow.close();
                    }
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    activeInfoWindow = infowindow;
                });
            });

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, options);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{YOUR-API-KEY}}&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
</head>
```

As long as anyone can see I am using in here two scripts with maps. 
With this code everything works out in chrome, but it doesn't work in Mozzila (thank God I have only those two browsers to support). The map which is supposed to show up on every page is just not working. And this is the error that is shown in mozzila console:

> uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
>   You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on
>   this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

And this is the console error that I have from Chrome:

> Uncaught Ob {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Ob (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…kLEDNWcj0IwFZ_Io84oExuE8g&callback=initMap:162:56"}
>   But everything is displayed in Chrome and one map is missing from Mozzila.
>   Could someone else offer to me a solution ?

UPDATE: 
If you are asking yourself why do I call api twice. Because if I call it only once from the top of the head then two maps are lost from both browsers. I believe that it has connection with calling the function back because in one browser (read Mozilla) it calls it if the maps api is called from the top and in Chrome it works if the api call is from bottom. 
And if I put it inside once then in respective browsers it says that it misses the InitMap.

Comment: Why are you calling the api twice? Algo, just checking, I imagine you removed the api key when pasting the code here right?

Comment: Yes, I removed the key because of our clients who provided us with it. Look into edit of a question for the answer to your first question.

Comment: So in this page you have two maps, one in the header and the other one in the body which again calls the api?

Comment: No, we are using one time in a header and two times in body. Sorry. 
Maybe you can visit iclei.org and see it under global and in iclei.org/en/our_network.html and iclei.org/en/members-search.html

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough in my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using initMap and initAutocomplete on same html page google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085722/using-initmap-and-initautocomplete-on-same-html-page-google-maps)

Comment: Hey, I just add it once and it works all over. It even loads the map in mozilla firefox also, but without the pins. Looking at it currently. If it is what I think it is, then I am going to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=you+have+included+the+Google+Maps+JavaScript+API+multiple+times+on+this+page ...

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for the answer. I have tried to NOT include twice google maps into my web pages, but as  described already it gives different behaviour in different browsers. So this means that everything works in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Mozilla ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to add to the maps and jquery.main.js and analytics is

> defer

at the end of the script tag. 
For those of you who are asking yourself why is that ? This is because (by my research) google.maps and google.analytics share some library and

What this does is that it loads the javascript after the page and after everything else has been loaded. (CSS and the rest of the javascripts) and it also calls it respectively the two libraries (analytics and maps).