# Adding search (Places) to an existing map with external KML data

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, search, kml

I've been researching an answer to this but have ultimately only found ways to create a searchable map by creating an entirely new map without my KML data. I have a map with markers and simply want to add an autocomplete search bar to the map that I have.

Everything I've tried breaks the map (removing the map completely) and leaving me with a search bar that is non functional. I have added Places to my billing, and as mentioned, I have the map with the markers in place via an external KML file. How can I add a search functionality to what I already have?

Here is my map code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>HCV Providers</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      "use strict";
      function initMap() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {
            lat: 30.9843,
            lng: 91.9623
          }
        });
        const ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: "https://louisianahealthhub.org/HCVProviders.kml",
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**full page with errors:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HCV Providers</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initAutocomplete&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    "use strict";

    function initMap() {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: {
          lat: 30.9843,
          lng: 91.9623
        }
      });
      const ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: "https://louisianahealthhub.org/HCVProviders.kml",
        map: map
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    "use strict";

    // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
    // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
    // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.
    // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
    function initAutocomplete() {}); // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

    const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
    const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input); // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.

    map.addListener("bounds_changed", () => {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });
    let markers = []; // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.

    searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
      const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      } // Clear out the old markers.

      markers.forEach(marker => {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = []; // For each place, get the icon, name and location.

      const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(place => {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }

        const icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        }; // Create a marker for each place.

        markers.push(
          new google.maps.Marker({
            map,
            icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          })
        );

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" />
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: edited your question to add the "full/broken" version of the code (added Google's test key so the map would work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the updated code you posted, you have two "init" functions.

I get 3 javascript errors with that code:

- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`
- `You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`
- `Uncaught (in promise) re {message: "initAutocomplete is not a function",`

It is also a duplicate of [Using initMap and initAutocomplete on same html page google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085722/using-initmap-and-initautocomplete-on-same-html-page-google-maps)

The simplest fix is add the [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete) constructor to the `initMap` function existing code.

Relevant lines (from Google's [autocomplete example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)):

```
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
  // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
  // bounds option in the request.
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
  autocomplete.setFields(
    ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

```js
"use strict";

function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 30.9843,
      lng: 91.9623
    }
  });
  const ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "https://louisianahealthhub.org/HCVProviders.kml",
    map: map
  });
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
  // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
  // bounds option in the request.
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
  autocomplete.setFields(
    ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<title>HCV Providers</title>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=places" defer></script>
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
```