# Multiple Google maps on one page with settimeouts and event.listeners

Tags: javascript, google-maps

For the sake of this argument I have my two maps callbacks here:

```
function initMap() {
  // The location of Intersection One
  var intersection_one = {lat: [lat1], lng: [lng1]};
  var image = 'assets/images/map_icon_marker.ico';
  // The map, centered at Intersection One
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map_one'), {zoom: 18, center: intersection_one, mapTypeId: 'satellite'});
  // The marker, positioned at Intersection One
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: intersection_one, map: map,  icon: image});
  map.addListener("center_changed", () => {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
  });
   // Allow users to click on the map to open in a new window
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@[lat/lng1m/data=")
});
// Allow users to click on the marker to open in a new window
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@5[lat/lng1m/data=data=")
});
}

function initMap() {
  // The location of Intersection Two
  var intersection_two = {lat: [lat2], lng: [lng2]};
  var image = 'assets/images/map_icon_marker.ico';
  // The map, centered at Intersection Two
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map_two'), {zoom: 19, center: intersection_two, mapTypeId: 'satellite'});
  // The marker, positioned at Intersection One
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: intersection_two, map: map2,  icon: image});
  map.addListener("center_changed", () => {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      map.panTo(marker2.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
  });
   // Allow users to click on the map to open in a new window
  google.maps.event.addListener(map2, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@[lat/lng1]z")
});
// Allow users to click on the marker to open in a new window
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@[lat/lng1]zz")
});
}
```

I know this way isn't working, but I am I wondering how I can chain together two setTimeOut functions (centering the map) and two addListener functions that allow the map to be clicked on and opened in a new window?

When I string the two setTimeout functions together like this (full code):

```
function initMap() {
  // The location of Intersection One
  var intersection_one = {lat: 55.777034, lng: 37.583926};
  var intersection_two = {lat: -33.7386872, lng: 150.9154922};
  var image = 'assets/images/map_icon_marker.ico';
  // The map, centered at Intersection One
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map_one'), {zoom: 18, center: intersection_one, mapTypeId: 'satellite'});
   var map2 = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map_two'), {zoom: 19, center: intersection_two, mapTypeId: 'satellite'});    
  // The marker, positioned at Intersection One
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: intersection_one, map: map,  icon: image});
  map.addListener("center_changed", () => {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: intersection_two, map: map2,  icon: image});
  map.addListener("center_changed", () => {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      map2.panTo(marker2.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
    });

   // Allow users to click on the map to open in a new window
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@55.7769838,37.5835604,81m/data=!3m1!1e3")
});
// Allow users to click on the marker to open in a new window
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@55.7769838,37.5835604,81m/data=!3m1!1e3")
});
}
```

I can get the first map to re-center, but not the second map, unless the first map re-centers. So if a user just moves the second map, it does not re-center unless they move the first map.

Comment: You can't have two functions with the same name.  Possible duplicate of [Using initMap and initAutocomplete on same html page google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085722/using-initmap-and-initautocomplete-on-same-html-page-google-maps)

Comment: Yeah, I know I can't use the same name - the script up there was for argument sake. I can have multiple maps, just use those variables map2 etc. That isn't an issue. The issue is getting the setTimeout and addListener functions to work on two or more maps. Getting the maps in place is easy.

Comment: What error are you getting in the javascript console?

Comment: In your second function, you probably want to reference `map2` in the `setTimeout` function (looks like a typo to me, or a copy/paste error).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual issue.

Comment: What error are you getting in the javascript console? 

Damn... I undid it all before checking (I forget to check the console). But when I tried to chain the setTimeout and Listener the maps didn't load at all (I searched here for ideas how to do it). Or, if the maps loaded they became unclickable and didn't re-centre.

Comment: I get `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: lat1 is not defined` with the posted code.

Comment: I'll put code in a new comment and what is happening.

Comment: Please update your question ([edit] it) with the correct code (preferably a [mcve]) and any error messages you are seeing that you can't figure out.

Comment: I edited my opening question, working on one problem at a time. The re-centering. I can get the first map to recenter but not the second map. The second map will recenter if I recenter the first map. :)

Comment: You still have a typo, now in the second `center_changed` listener.  That should be `map2.addListener`, not `map.addListener`.  ([working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5fva8jem/2/))

Comment: Good spotting! Thank you! I didn't see that. It does work. I can have multiple re-aligning maps now. That's great! One thing down. The next is getting them to all open in a new window.

Comment: haha... it works! I did have it right! Arrrrrg... how annoying. It must have been that typo. Thank you for spotting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (there was typos in the original). It is possible to have multiple maps and multiple setTimeout and multiple addListener functions to multiple Google maps. Here is the code I used:

```
function initMap() {
  // The location of Intersection One
  var intersection_one = {lat: 55.777034, lng: 37.583926};
  var intersection_two = {lat: -33.738541, lng: 150.917933};
  var image = 'assets/images/map_icon_marker.ico';
  // The map, centered at Intersection One
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map_one'), {zoom: 18, center: intersection_one, mapTypeId: 'satellite'});
   var map2 = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map_two'), {zoom: 19, center: intersection_two, mapTypeId: 'satellite'});    
  // The marker, positioned at Intersection One
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: intersection_one, map: map,  icon: image});
  map.addListener("center_changed", () => {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: intersection_two, map: map2,  icon: image});
  map2.addListener("center_changed", () => {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      map2.panTo(marker2.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
    });

   // Allow users to click on the map to open in a new window
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@55.7769838,37.5835604,81m/data=!3m1!1e3")
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map2, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@-33.7385745,150.9177533,120m/data=!3m1!1e3")
});
// Allow users to click on the marker to open in a new window
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@55.7769838,37.5835604,81m/data=!3m1!1e3")
});
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function(){
     window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@-33.7385745,150.9177533,120m/data=!3m1!1e3")
});
}
```