# Use 2 Google Maps API keys in one html page

Tags: html, api, google-maps, api-key

I am trying to use 2 strings of `<script>` to load 2 Google Maps, one at the time.
Each string has a different KEY, and each string loads a different "callback".
Then I have 2 divs with 2 different ids. Each id gets loaded in "standard mode" or in `(prefers-color-scheme: dark)`.
The problem is that it works intermittently, if I refresh the page sometimes the map disappears, sometimes it loads... random.
Here is how I have set it up. Please let me know if someone can fix this :)

Html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=emptygmap" async defer></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYOTHERKEY&callback=emptygmapdue" async defer></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="lightmaps">
    <div id="gmap"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="darkmaps">
    <div id="gmapdark"></div>
  </div>

<script>
function emptygmap() {
    //mappa uno
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.855027,-80.1874731);
    //mappa due
    var myLatlngBel = new google.maps.LatLng(26.1463041,-81.7958914);
    //variabile icone marker
    var icona = {url: '../symb/icons8-marker-100.png',
        scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(40, 40)
    };
    
    //stile mappa uno e due
var emptystyle = [
    
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ff0000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "-25"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#444444"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "50"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ff0000"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": "18"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "-55"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            },
            {
                "color": "#4484a1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.province",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            },
            {
                "hue": "#ff0000"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "saturation": "0"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "50"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "50"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "50"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "1.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#f2f2f2"
            },
            {
                "saturation": "28"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "42"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "2.01"
            },
            {
                "weight": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "50"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "50"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": -100
            },
            {
                "lightness": 45
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "weight": "0.4"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "80"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "1.0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "weight": "0.15"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "0"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "1.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "weight": "0.60"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "gamma": "1.50"
            },
            {
                "weight": "1.60"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "weight": "0.20"
            },
            {
                "color": "#000000"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "71"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#fcfcfc"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": "-2"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "12"
            },
            {
                "gamma": "1.00"
            },
            {
                "color": "#cfdde8"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            },
            {
                "color": "#ff0000"
            }
        ]
    }
]

    //posizione mappa uno
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12.55,
        center: { lat: 25.84, lng: -80.16},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        rotateControl: false,
        gestureHandling: "auto",

        styles: emptystyle
    }
    //posizione mappa due
    var mapOptionsBel = {
        zoom: 12.55,
        center: { lat: 26.1267527, lng: -81.814762 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        rotateControl: false,
        gestureHandling: "auto",
        styles: emptystyle
    }

    //mappa uno
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), mapOptions);
    //mappa due
    var mapB = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmapnaples'), mapOptionsBel);      

    //marker e posizione mappa uno
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: myLatlng,
        icon: icona,
    });

    //marker e posizione mappa due
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:mapB,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
        draggable:false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: { lat: 26.1463041, lng: -81.7958914 },
        icon: icona,
    });
    //animazione e mappa uno e due
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
        markerB.setAnimation(google.mapB.Animation.DROP);
    }   
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    
    $(document).ready(function() {initialize();
    });
</script>


<script>
function emptygmapdue() {
    //mappa uno
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25.855027,-80.1874731);
    //mappa due
    var myLatlngBel = new google.maps.LatLng(26.1463041,-81.7958914);
    //variabile icone marker
    var icona = {url: '../symb/icons8-marker-50.png',
        scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(40, 40)
    };
    
    //stile mappa uno e due
var emptystyle = [
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": "-21"
            },
            {
                "color": "#929292"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "26"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 16
            },
            {
                "color": "#181c21"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1f2125"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "-2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1f2125"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            },
            {
                "weight": 1.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1f2125"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1f2125"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1f2125"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "30"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1f2125"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "9"
            },
            {
                "weight": 0.2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#1f2125"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "25"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#181c21"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "20"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#181c21"
            },
            {
                "lightness": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#282d32"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 17
            }
        ]
    }
]

    //posizione mappa uno
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12.55,
        center: { lat: 25.84, lng: -80.16},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        rotateControl: false,
        gestureHandling: "auto",

        styles: emptystyle
    }
    //posizione mappa due
    var mapOptionsBel = {
        zoom: 12.55,
        center: { lat: 26.1267527, lng: -81.814762 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        rotateControl: false,
        gestureHandling: "auto",
        styles: emptystyle
    }

    //mappa uno
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmapdark'), mapOptions);
    //mappa due
    var mapB = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmapnaplesdark'), mapOptionsBel);      

    //marker e posizione mappa uno
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: myLatlng,
        icon: icona,
    });

    //marker e posizione mappa due
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:mapB,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
        draggable:false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: { lat: 26.1463041, lng: -81.7958914 },
        icon: icona,
    });
    //animazione e mappa uno e due
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
        markerB.setAnimation(google.mapB.Animation.DROP);
    }   
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    
    $(document).ready(function() {initialize();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
div#darkmaps {display: block;}
div#lightmaps {display: none;}
}

#gmap, #gmapdark {width:100%;height:45vw;}
#darkmaps {display: none;}
#lightmaps {display: block;}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you need to load 2 maps on the same website with a different key? Anyway you are **not** expected to load the API multiple times on the same page (your JS console should tell you about that).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using initMap and initAutocomplete on same html page google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085722/using-initmap-and-initautocomplete-on-same-html-page-google-maps)

Comment: Yes I agree :) I started using 1 API but I could not make it work... I just tried to use 2 to see if it was working, but I guess I did it worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommend nor supported to load the Google Maps JS API twice on a single page. You will get a console warning about this.

Problem:

- double billing
- collision and unexpected behaviors

Solutions:

- Use same key for both maps on page(not sure why this wouldn't be preferred).
- If you really must, one of the maps could be embedded in an iframe.